# Some field extensions with coprime degrees

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $L/K$ be a finite field extension with degree $m$. And let $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $m$ and $n$ are coprime. Show the following:

If there is a $a\in \mathbb K$ such that an $n$-th root of $a$ lies in $L$ then we have already $a\in \mathbb K$.

My attempt:

The field extension $K(\sqrt[n]{a})/K$ has degree smaller $n$. The minimal polynomial of
$\sqrt[n]{a}$ namely $m_{\sqrt[n]{a}}(X)\in K[X]$ divides $X^n-a$. I.e. let $k$ be the degree of the minimal polynomial, then $k|n$.

But because of the formula $[L:K]=[L:K(\sqrt[n]{a}]\cdot [K(\sqrt[n]{a}):K]$ $k|m$, hence $k=1$ and hence our conclusion follows because $[K(\sqrt[n]{a}):K]=1$ yields $\sqrt[n]{a}\in K$ .

Can someone go through it? Thanks.

Comment: I guess the conclusion that $k|n$ is wrong.. Edit: But it may have another prove if we can assume that $X^n-a$ has distinct roots. Is that true? I am actually quite sure that it is.

Comment: I thought I did a mistake because I wrote: "The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[n]{a}$ divides $X^n-a$, hence the degree of the minimal polynomial also divides the degree of $X^n-a$. But this is wrong in general, I guess...From your second answer I conclude that this type of polynomials are not separable in general?

Comment: No, this arumgent does not work. It could happen that we have i.e. $m=12$, $n=7$, and the polynomial $X^7-a$ could split into irreducible factors of degree $4$ and $3$ over $K$. One has to exclude this.
The solution can not only deal with degree-and-divisibility-arguments. We somehow have to use that we have the special polynomial of the form $X^n-a$.

Comment: I actually thought that $X^n-a$ is separable with one real root and the others are the powers of one imaginary root and a product with the real root. (If $X^n-a$ would be separable I might have a correct prove of the statement)

Answer (score 0):

The non-separable case is actually not the problem: Let $p$ be the characteristic.

If $X^n-a$ is not separable, we have $p|n$ and we can write $X^n-a=(X^d-\sqrt[p^r]{a})^{p^r}$ with the inner polynomial being separable. By assumption $\sqrt[n]{a} \in L$, hence $\sqrt[p^r]{a} \in L$. But $\sqrt[p^r]{a}$ is purely inseparable over $K$ and seprable over $K$, because it lies in the separable extension $L/K$. This extension is separable because $m$ and $p$ must be co-prime. Thus $\sqrt[p^r]{a} \in K$. So we are reduced to the separable case with the polynomial $X^d-\sqrt[p^r]{a} \in K[X]$, since $d$ and $m$ are co-prime.